# Dialog flow chat bot token expires every 5 minutes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have been working on a project with unity about chat bots using dialog flow,
the problem I am facing is as follows: I have to run some commands in order to retrieve the token from google in terminal then a C# script uses this token to run some functions but the problem is that the token expires every 5 minutes since I m consuming the API so is there a way to automate the process in a bash script file where It can run the commands and get the token then it is directly used in the C# script.

- [accessing agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0y1V.png)
- [Getting the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prvtx.png)

## DialogflowAPIScript

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using JsonData;


public class DialogflowAPIScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    void Start()
    {
        i0tBjGc2WlRT9GePIqe1_j5Xq9flXHMGJWnn5sEjNHyG1VfMFqtt3WapHAVo2-RwvPNKRTHI0BkF9OVUzZJ5OWJEILr64_ge1tgcbS7AA"));

        
        StartCoroutine(PostRequest("https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/newagent-taqyfj/agent/sessions/34563:detectIntent",
                              "ya29.c.Ko4B0AeMSB_eB-0DumT7ubxKoJc47TMOKhgls589I-F8whsTbnZvAgFn6Ft-sqwcFPI1n_-CQIp4zk-e3Ip9lVvXvrJFOfPmoejayJhjHR9Gu36XsulR71_iHGnvb8m4aYbkBF9tnkA05cJahNyVZoK5SWR3EgAb4XofkMfp7Qt8vtnMa6J-Q89YZevUk3VfaA"));
    }


    void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator PostRequest(String url, String AccessToken)
    {
        UnityWebRequest postRequest = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody();
        requestBody.queryInput = new QueryInput();
        requestBody.queryInput.text = new TextInput();
        requestBody.queryInput.text.text = "hello";
        requestBody.queryInput.text.languageCode = "en";

        string jsonRequestBody = JsonUtility.ToJson(requestBody, true);
        Debug.Log(jsonRequestBody);

        byte[] bodyRaw = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonRequestBody);
    
        postRequest.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        postRequest.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        postRequest.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        //postRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        yield return postRequest.SendWebRequest();

        if (postRequest.isNetworkError || postRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(postRequest.responseCode);
            Debug.Log(postRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log("Response: " + postRequest.downloadHandler.text);

        
            byte[] resultbyte = postRequest.downloadHandler.data;
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultbyte);
            ResponseBody content = (ResponseBody)JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseBody>(result);
            Debug.Log(content.queryResult.fulfillmentText);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator GetAgent(String AccessToken)
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/newagent-taqyfj/agent");

        www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
        
            Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);

                    byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
}
```

## request RequestBody

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace JsonData
{
    v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#QueryParameters

    public class RequestBody
    {
        public QueryInput queryInput;
        
        public string inputAudio;
    }


    public class QueryInput
    {
        public TextInput text;
        //public InputAudioConfig audioConfig;
    }
    

    public class InputAudioConfig
    {
        public AudioEncoding audioEncoding;
        public int sampleRateHertz;
        public String languageCode;
        public String[] phraseHints;
    }

    public enum AudioEncoding
    {
        AUDIO_ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED,
        AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16,
        AUDIO_ENCODING_FLAC,
        AUDIO_ENCODING_MULAW,
        AUDIO_ENCODING_AMR,
        AUDIO_ENCODING_AMR_WB,
        AUDIO_ENCODING_OGG_OPUS,
        AUDIO_ENCODING_SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE
    }

public enum WebhookState
    {
        STATE_UNSPECIFIED,
        WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED,
        WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED_FOR_SLOT_FILLING
    }

    
    public class ResponseBody
    {
        public string responseId;
        public QueryResult queryResult;
        public Status webhookStatus;
    }

    public class QueryResult
    {
        public string queryText;
        public string languageCode;
        public int speechRecognitionConfidence;
        public string action;
        public Struct parameters;
        public bool allRequiredParamsPresent;
        public string fulfillmentText;
        public Message[] fulfillmentMessages;
        public string webhookSource;
        public Struct webhookPayload;
        public Context[] outputContexts;
        public Intent intent;
        public int intentDetectionConfidence;
        public Struct diagnosticInfo;
    }
    
    [Serializable]
    public class Status
    {
        public int code;
        public string message;
        public Object[] details;
    }

    
    [Serializable]
    public class Intent
    {
        public string name;
        public string displayName;
        public WebhookState webhookState;
        public int priority;
        public bool isFallback;
    }

    

    public class Context
    {
        public string name;
    }


    public class Struct
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Value> fields;
    }


    public class Value
    {
        public NullValue null_value;
        public double number_value;
        public string string_value;
        public bool bool_value;
        public Struct struct_value;
        public ListValue list_value;

        public void ForBool(bool value){
            this.bool_value = value;
        }

        public void ForString(string value)
        {
            this.string_value = value;
        }

        public void ForNumber(double number){
            this.number_value = number;
        }

        public void ForNull()
        {
            this.null_value = NullValue.null_vaule;
        }

        public void ForStruct(Struct value){
            this.struct_value = value;
        }

        public void ForList(ListValue value){
            this.list_value = value;
        }
    }

    public enum NullValue
    {
        null_vaule
    }

    
    public class ListValue{
        public Value values;

    }

    
    public class Text{
        public string[] text;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Message{
        public Text text;
    }




}```
````

Comment: This is a good question; however, it's a bit hard to read. You can improve this question by removing code that is not relevant to the question, such as the additional classes in your namespace. On the problem itself, does it need to be a Bash script? You can accomplish this using C#. Two potential solutions: keep a timer that will asynchronously call a function every five minutes, or refresh the token on-demand when you need to make an API request but it fails because of an invalid session.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . it dose not have to be a bash script  the problem is how can i execute those commands on a C#  i'm only familiar video game dev with C#  . ill be glad if u refer me a link or information where can i  learn to do it